# How do I convert this endpoint from javascript to typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, socket.io, t3

I am developing a chat app using the t3 stack and I have got this socket endpoint working fine using javascript but I would like to now convert it to typescript and I am struggling.

```
import { Server } from "Socket.IO";

const SocketHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Socket is already running");
  } else {
    console.log("Socket is initializing");
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("update-messages", (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("update-messages", msg);
      });
      socket.on("user-typing", (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-typing", msg);
      });
    });
  }
  res.end();
};

export default SocketHandler;
```

I translated it to typescript using any as the type for the response but I am not happy with this.

Comment: Just use a generic arguments of `Response` to indicate extended type of `res`

Answer (score 0):

I have converted it to Typescript with some help from @Anatoly:

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

const SocketHandler = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Socket is already running");
  } else {
    console.log("Socket is initializing");
    const io: Server = new Server(res.socket.server);
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("update-messages", (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("update-messages", msg);
      });
      socket.on("user-typing", (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("user-typing", msg);
      });
    });
  }
  res.end();
};

export default SocketHandler;
```

You just had to import the `Request` and `Response` types from express.

You can find some information here: https://plainenglish.io/blog/typed-express-request-and-response-with-typescript

Hope this helped!
Regards, Alvin cheng